# Performance of CASE WHEN nested through CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-performance, sql-execution-plan

I have a performance problem which I think I may have solved, but I need help understanding why the possible solution improves SQL Server's behavior, and most importantly, whether it is reliable (eg, unlikely to suddenly become slow as the data grows and changes, or with simple code alterations). I'm also open to better solutions altogether. There's a lot of context here, so please bear with me. I have been doing my development and testing against SQL Server 2008 R2.

I'm working on a system which examines certain conditions on data, and depending on those conditions, performs different actions automatically in the background. These same conditions are used to show information to the user, such as when the next action will occur for a given entry in `dbo.Cases`, or why no action will be performed.

There is a view which gathers all of the data for these conditions, and selects the conditions as bit flags using `CASE WHEN` statements. These columns can either be used by the UI, or used in a `WHERE` clause by an automated polling process.

The conditions are often used in the same way, so it was desirable to avoid repeating them everywhere. "Roll-up columns" were created which examine the other conditions: IsSubmittable and IsAutomaticallySubmittable.

Here's basically what the view looks like:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwDataExtended
AS
WITH

Data AS (

SELECT      Cases.CNR,
            Cases.CNRLink,
            IsActiveCompany =
                CASE
                    WHEN Companies.IsActive IS NULL THEN CAST(0 as BIT)
                    ELSE Companies.IsActive
                END,
            IsOpen =
                CASE
                    WHEN Cases.SCODE = 'O' THEN CAST(1 as BIT)
                    ELSE CAST(0 as BIT)
                END,
            IsReopened =
                CASE
                    WHEN Cases.SCODE = 'R' THEN CAST(1 as BIT)
                    ELSE CAST(0 as BIT)
                END,
            IsCompanyClassCode =
                CASE
                    WHEN CompanyClassCode.CompanyClassCodeID IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(1 as BIT)
                    ELSE CAST(0 as BIT)
                END
            --several other conditions

FROM        dbo.Cases with (nolock)

LEFT JOIN   dbo.Companies with (nolock)
    ON      Companies.CompanyCode = Cases.CompanyCode
    AND     Companies.CustomerLevelTypeCode = 'CUSTOMER'

LEFT JOIN   dbo.ClassCodes with (nolock)
    ON      ClassCodes.ClassCode = Cases.ClassCode

--identify enabled company class codes
LEFT JOIN   dbo.ISO_Search_CompanyClassCode CompanyClassCode with (nolock)
    ON      CompanyClassCode.CompanyCode = Cases.CompanyCode
    AND     CompanyClassCode.ClassCode = ClassCodes.ClassCode
    AND     CompanyClassCode.EnableOn <= GETDATE()

--lots of other joins

) --end CTE Data

AddIsSubmittable as (
    select      *,
                IsSubmittable = case when

                    IsActiveCompany = 1
                    and     IsCompanyClassCode = 1
                    --7 other similar conditions

                    then cast(1 as bit)
                    else cast(0 as bit)
                end
    from        Data
), --end CTE AddIsSubmittable

AddIsAutomaticallySubmittable as (
    select      *,
                IsAutomaticallySubmittable = case when

                    IsSubmittable = 1
                    and     (IsOpen = 1 OR IsReopened = 1)
                    --2 other similar conditions

                    then cast(1 as bit)
                    else cast(0 as bit)
                end
    from        AddIsSubmittable
) --end CTE AddIsAutomaticallySubmittable

select      CNR,
            CNRLINK,
            IsActiveCompany,
            IsOpen,
            IsReopened,
            IsCompanyClassCode,
            IsISOSubmittable,
            IsAutomaticallySubmittable

from        AddIsAutomaticallySubmittable
```

And here is an example of how an automated polling process uses it:

```
DECLARE CURSOR_NEW CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT      DISTINCT
                d.CNR

    FROM        dbo.vwDataExtended d with(nolock)

    WHERE       d.IsAutomaticallySubmittable = 1
    AND         --process-specific conditions
```

Conceptually, this design is nice because it ensures that the UI code is always in sync with the code for the automated processes. However, it requires that the view be very efficient, since some of these processes run fairly frequently (the main one is on a 10 minute interval), and there's nearly 3 million rows in `dbo.Cases`.

With the above implementation, the queries for the polling processes run very slowly. Looking at the execution plan, what happens is all of the data for the roll-up column for every row in `dbo.Cases` is gathered up, and then it is filtered close to the end. The other conditions which are specific to each polling process are not handled as poorly.

The potential solution that I have found is to remove the roll-up columns from `vwDataExtended` and add each one as a separate view with their conditions in the `WHERE` clause, as thus:

```
create view dbo.vwDataExtended_IsSubmittable
as

select  CNR,
        CNRLINK,
        IsActiveCompany,
        IsOpen,
        IsReopened,
        IsCompanyClassCode

from    dbo.vwDataExtended with(nolock)

where   IsActiveCompany = 1
and     IsCompanyClassCode = 1
--7 other similar conditions
go

create view dbo.vwDataExtended_IsAutomaticallySubmittable
as
select  CNR,
        CNRLINK,
        IsActiveCompany,
        IsOpen,
        IsReopened,
        IsCompanyClassCode

from    dbo.vwDataExtended_IsSubmittable with(nolock)

where   (IsOpen = 1 OR IsReopened = 1)
--2 other similar conditions
```

Then the polling process's query is modified thus:

```
DECLARE CURSOR_NEW CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT      DISTINCT
                d.CNR

    FROM        dbo.vwDataExtended_IsAutomaticallySubmittable d with(nolock)

    WHERE       --process-specific conditions
```

The execution plans generated for this implementation are DRAMATICALLY improved, showing that SQL Server is using the contents of `vwDataExtended`'s `CASE WHEN` statements as predicates for lookups and scans, thus greatly limiting the number of rows it examines.

This implementation does come with a cost, though: the UI must `LEFT JOIN` the new views with `dbo.vwDataExtended` in order to achieve functionality equivalent to the original `dbo.vwDataExtended`. This is very inefficient and makes for some rather busy execution plans, although the execution time is likely still acceptable (if only barely).

Coming back to the original question: Why does this improve SQL Server's behavior so much? Is there any documentation that can be used to explain the difference? Is there perhaps an alternative to this design that doesn't involve duplicating logic all over the place?

Comment: IIRC a CTE is not stored once accessed and has to be re-evaluated each time you use it. In this example the `Data` CTE is referenced 3 times. If you set that core CTE to write to a table variable, and used that instead, it would only need to be processed once.

Comment: The CTEs are used in a chain (one selects from another until the view's select at the bottom), so it should only be used once. I've never seen anything in the execution plan that suggests multiple uses are occurring.

Comment: If that was true this query would return the same guid in both columns: `;with cte1 as ( select id = newid() ) ,cte2 as (select id from cte1 ) select cte1.id, cte2.id from cte1, cte2`

Comment: What my view is doing is more along the lines of this: `;with cte1 as ( select id = newid() ) ,cte2 as (select id from cte1 ) select cte2.id from cte2`

Answer (score 0):

I avoid using CTEs unless there is a need for recursion, or, a CTE can be reused in the final query. Neither condition applies here and hence I would not use CTEs for this at all.

You are using CTEs to "add" based on some prior calculation, but there are 2 other techniques for this.

```
/* a simple "derived table" (or "inline view") */

    select ..., comp.IsActiveCompany
    from (
           select *, IsActiveCompany =
               case when Companies.IsActive IS NULL THEN CAST(0 as BIT)
                                ELSE Companies.IsActive END
         ) comp

/* using the apply operator for the calculation */
.
    select ..., ca1.IsActiveCompany
    from dbo.Companies
        OUTER APPLY (
             SELECT 
                    CASE
                        WHEN Companies.IsActive IS NULL THEN CAST(0 as BIT)
                        ELSE Companies.IsActive
                    END
            ) as ca1 (IsActiveCompany)
```

Both techniques give you the ability to refer to some prior calculation by reference to the given column alias.

I would be tempted to try using OUTER APPLY for those calculations that you want to reference by aliases, and then I would also treat the overall view as a derived table removing all need for CTEs. Clearly some of this is a guess for what will best suit so continue to use execution plans to investigate further.

e.g.

```
select      CNR,
            CNRLINK,
            IsActiveCompany,
            IsOpen,
            IsReopened,
            IsCompanyClassCode,
            IsISOSubmittable,
            IsAutomaticallySubmittable
from (
        SELECT      Cases.CNR,
                    Cases.CNRLink,

                    CA1.IsActiveCompany,

                   IsSubmittable = case when

                            CA1.IsActiveCompany = 1
                            and     IsCompanyClassCode = 1
                            --7 other similar conditions

                            then cast(1 as bit)
                            else cast(0 as bit)
                        end

                   -- lots of stuff missing to put back in

        FROM        dbo.Cases with (nolock)

        LEFT JOIN   dbo.Companies with (nolock)
            ON      Companies.CompanyCode = Cases.CompanyCode
            AND     Companies.CustomerLevelTypeCode = 'CUSTOMER'
            OUTER APPLY (
                         SELECT 
                                CASE
                                    WHEN Companies.IsActive IS NULL THEN CAST(0 as BIT)
                                    ELSE Companies.IsActive
                                END
                        ) as ca1 (IsActiveCompany)

        LEFT JOIN   dbo.ClassCodes with (nolock)
            ON      ClassCodes.ClassCode = Cases.ClassCode

        --identify enabled company class codes
        LEFT JOIN   dbo.ISO_Search_CompanyClassCode CompanyClassCode with (nolock)
            ON      CompanyClassCode.CompanyCode = Cases.CompanyCode
            AND     CompanyClassCode.ClassCode = ClassCodes.ClassCode
            AND     CompanyClassCode.EnableOn <= GETDATE()

        --lots of other joins

    ) AS derived
```

Comment: Using APPLY seemed promising after converting a few of the columns to use it, but when I converted the rest, SQL Server stopped using the contained comparisons as predicates. So instead of using an index to scan for `SCODE = 'O' OR SCODE = 'R'`, it read all rows in `dbo.Cases`, computed the value of the expression, and later filtered by the expression (but not before reading a bunch of other joined tables...). Adding IsSubmittable and IsAutomaticallySubmittable as columns proved even more disastrous. :/

Comment: Impossible to help much via these snippets I'm afraid.  I suspect it probably will take trial and error, and you might try using a mixtures of both techniques selectively. Note we know "not a sod" about your table/columns/indexes or the data in them. But I wouldn't try CTEs for what you have explained through this question.

Comment: I didn't want to make this into a 20 page exercise :P It's already much longer than the average SO question, and it would take longer than I have to put the full schema on sqlfiddle. I think part of the problem is poor row count estimates, but don't know how to improve them; semi-randomly throwing statistics and/or indexes on things isn't helping. I have been able to use APPLY as a way to tell SQL Server "hey, don't use this column for lookups", but that feels very hacky and potentially unreliable.

Comment: using APPLY isn't a hack and it can be surprisingly efficient - good luck